# Как перезапустить сервис приложения после отключения/включения

Tags: android

Запускается приложение через BroadcastReceiver, но не сервис (хотя именно он прописан в приемнике BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: action может одинаковый? код манифеста покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: и код самого ресивера.